# CAKEPHP - 'isUnique' field validation message

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I've read all the questions related to the subject but nothing solved my problem.

I'm using cakephp `$validate` on the model, is working fine, but I need to put a message identifying the error, I've put the attribute message in array but it doesn't appear anywhere.

If anyone can help me and give examples, please comment here.

```
public $validate = [
        'number' => [
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Serial number should be unique.'
        ],
    ];
```

Form input:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="form-label" for="serial">Serial number&nbsp;</label><br>
        <input id="serial" name="serial" value="<?php echo $data['serial']; ?>" type="text" data-bv-notempty="true" required="required" class="form-control" <?php echo $readonly; ?>>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Form create:

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    "role" => "form",
    "data-toggle" => "validator",
));
```

Comment: Is it cakephp version 2 or 3 ?

Comment: version 2, can u help me?

Comment: Please provide your html input field code, How you have written you input field ?

Comment: i edited my post with the codes!!! sorry

Comment: Here your field name is serial and you have added your validation in number !! Are you ensuring your validation is working ?

Comment: seems you're not using FormHelper to create yout input. Use `$this->Form->input(...)` if you want cake to append error messages to your

Comment: @AlimonKarim my code is in portuguese, i needed transtate it to put here and i didnt note, but the name in both is 'nserie' that means serial, ill fix it!! (my first question, sorry)

Comment: @arilia i will do it, just a minute and i show the result!! thanks

Comment: @arilia now its working fine!!!!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's not rendering the error message because you haven't included the code that does so.

The code in your view should look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="form-label" for="serial">Serial number&nbsp;</label><br>

    <input id="serial" name="serial" value="<?php echo $data['serial']; ?>" type="text" data-bv-notempty="true" required="required" class="form-control" <?php echo $readonly; ?>>

    <div class="help-block with-errors">
        <? if ($this->Form->isFieldError('serial')) {
            echo $this->Form->error('serial');
        } ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Instead of hard coding the HTML for the input field, you could perhaps use FormHelper::input(), which takes care of everything (including errors) for you.

From the FormHelper page in the manual: [Displaying and checking errors](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#displaying-and-checking-errors)